# Why do we specify header files for targets in Makefile?

Tags: c, makefile, header, header-files

I'm trying to understand Makefile. I understand the hole concept of the dependency tree, but why do we include `.h` files for the `.o` targets that include certain header file. Here is an example:

```c
// main.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include "math.h"

int main() {
    printf("%d\n", magic_number);
    printf("%d\n", square(5));
}
```

```c
// foo.h

const int magic_number = 10;

int square(int);
```

```c
// foo.c

int square(int value) {
    return value*value;
}
```

```
# -*- Makefile -*-

all: main

main: main.o foo.o
    gcc main.o foo.o -o main

main.o: main.c #foo.h <-----------
    gcc -c main.c

foo.o: foo.c
    gcc -c foo.c
```

I commented the part out where I would add the header file. Because that's my question, why does it have to be there? I did some testing and added some more `const int` variables to the header. Just looking at the Makefile (with commented out foo.h) it would only recompile the `main.c` file. There it would then access a variable from the header. So why does it look into the header file even thought it's not in the Makefile?

Comment: How *would* you rebuild your project if you modify one of your header files? Suppose your header file contains something like `#define N 100`, and later you change it to `#define N 1000`. How do you rebuild your project to use the new value of `N`? You may have dozens of source files in the project, some of which depend on that header and some which don't. If you have set up your dependences correctly in makefile, just one call to `make` will do it -- everything that needs to be recompiled will be recompiled.

Answer (score 1):

Makefiles track dependencies - in this case it is an explicit dependency.

Specifying that `main.o` depends on both `main.c` and `foo.h` means that any time either file changes, `main.o` will be rebuilt.

If you didn't have that explicit dependency chain, then you could change `foo.h` in a way which renders `main.c` uncompilable, but Make wouldn't know about it so would not rebuild it when it should.

Comment: Yeah you put it better. That's exactly what I mean. I just can't think of a change to foo.h that would render main.c uncompatible.

Comment: If you changed the return type of `magic_number()` to be `char *`, that'd be one way.

Comment: Yes, but then I'd also change the implenetiation of foo.c which it specified in the foo.o target. Which in return is specified in the main target. So I'd would still work, right?

Comment: If you _don't_ change `main.c`'s use of `magic_number()` you've got an error which the compiler will throw at you.

Comment: But I'd also get an error with foo.h in main.o's target because it is char now. Even if it would recompile the main.c... I still don't understand this.

Answer (score 1):

There are tons of ways that a header file can change in such a way that a source file doesn't need to also change, but yet the program is malformed if the source file is not rebuilt.  Here's one simple example: say we have this source:

```
// foo.h
struct foo {
    int f;
};

int getfoo(const struct foo* f);

// foo.c
#include "foo.h"

int getfoo(const struct foo* f)
{
    return f->f;
}

// main.c
#include "foo.h"

int main()
{
    struct foo f = {1};
    return getfoo(&f);
}
```

You compile everything and all is well.  Now suppose you modify `foo.h` like this:

```
// foo.h
struct foo {
    const char* val;  // added value
    int f;
};

int getfoo(const struct foo* f);
```

And you modify `main.c` like this:

```
// main.c
#include "foo.h"

int main()
{
    struct foo f = {"hello", 1};
    return getfoo(&f);
}
```

Now you run make and since you've modified `main.c` it is recompiled, but since you haven't modified `foo.c` it is not recompiled.

Now your program will certainly return a bogus value since `foo.o` thinks that the structure it was passed contains just a single integer, but the structure it was really passed from `main()` actually has a pointer plus an integer.